# Forward an email with a different content -VBA - Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Trying to forward an email with a different content. 
I tried to follow [these rules](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/run-vba-code-outlook/), but I do not get the emails.

Here is the vba code:

```
Public WithEvents objInbox As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInbox = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set objInboxItems = objInbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objForward As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
        Set objMail = Item
        'If it is a specific new email
        If (objMail.SenderEmailAddress = "incomingemail@test.com") And (objMail.Subject = "Job is complete") Then
            Set objForward = objMail.Forward
            'Customize the forward subject, body and recipients
            With objForward
                .Subject = "THIS IS A TEST"
                .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Type body here. </BODY></HTML>" & objForward.HTMLBody
                .Recipients.Add ("test@email.com")
                .Recipients.ResolveAll
                .Importance = olImportanceHigh
                .Send
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If it receives an email from incomingemail@test.com with a subject "Job is complete" - then sends an email to test@emailcom with a body : THIS IS A TEST

Comment: Have you checked the attributes on a couple test emails? In mine, the `.SenderEmailAddress` contains a LOT of extraneous data before it gets to the email.

Comment: For clarification, whats the actual problem? The emails aren't being SENT to test@email`.`com?  Have you tried changing your `.Send` to `.Display` to see if the email is ever actually generated?  Is this code triggering at all?